# JFreeChart Time Series

Tags: java, jfreechart, epoch

I am trying to generate a time series of the price data set I possess. All the times are kept as posix time, so milliseconds after 1970, so they require instantiation of a proper object that can be passed to TimeSeries. Is there any specific object that can use as a constructor parameter milliseconds and still provide info such as day/month/year etc., a bit like Java.util.Date class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're populating your `TimeSeries`, you can use the `add(RegularTimePeriod, Number)` method.

There are several implementations of `RegularTimePeriod`, including `Day` and `Millisecond`, depending on the structure of your data.

These are all jfreechart classes.

However, we found that in some of our applications, creating `TimeSeries` of `RegularTimePeriod` was memory inefficient - because you then have to create a new object for each time point in your series. As such, I found the best approach was to write our own implementation of `AbstractXYDataset` to which we could add our own time series objects. I should add that we then use `ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(...)`, passing in our implementation of `AbstractXYDataset`; this has the advantage of using a `DateAxis` for the x-axis.

Comment: Sure, but in your own implementation you still had to somehow convert milliseconds in long to some sort of object right?

Comment: @Boder02 - yes, but our time series objects use jsr310 date/time classes, so we convert to an Instant, which has a method toEpochMillisLong().